# How to set HTML code in "srcdoc" attribute of iframe?

Tags: php, iframe, smarty

```
<div id="email_content">
<iframe srcdoc="{$email_content}"></iframe>
</div>
```

As shown in below picture I am using iframe inside `div#email_content` to show exact preview of email content. I am trying to use `srcdoc` attribute to load email content in the iframe. Here the email content might be a plain text or HTML content designed through CkEditor. I tried using escape, htmlentities, etc. But the srcdoc attribute breaks because the attribute value contains pure HTML code and quotes.

Any work-around will be accepted.

Thanks!

Note: I don't want to use `src` attribute here.

[image]

Comment: Posted something but if it breaks for your html then you need to provide a sample HTML where it breaks

Comment: Avoid `htmlentities`! It's slower and the output will be larger because you don't need to replace *every* special character for srcdoc, just quotes. The other answer using `str_replace` is *much* more efficient.

Comment: `htmlentities()` also doesn't address the need to *double* escape ampersands (&) in the srcdoc string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `htmlentities` method in php

```
<?php
$str = '<a href="https://www.tarunlalwani.com">Go to tarunlalwani.com</a>';
echo htmlentities($str);
?>
```

And then assign that to `srcdoc`. It works as shown in below JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/zpx8qw1b/1/

Answer (score 7):

According to the [HTML5 specification for `<iframe>`](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-iframe-element.html), we need to replace the **quotes** and **ampersands** in the *srcdoc* string with HTML entities:

> In the HTML syntax, authors need only remember to use """ (U+0022) characters to wrap the attribute contents and then to escape all """ (U+0022) and U+0026 AMPERSAND (&) characters, and to specify the sandbox attribute, to ensure safe embedding of content.
>
> Notice the way that quotes have to be escaped (otherwise the srcdoc attribute would end prematurely), and the way raw ampersands (e.g. in URLs or in prose) mentioned in the sandboxed content have to be ***doubly*** escaped — once so that the ampersand is preserved when originally parsing the srcdoc attribute, and once more to prevent the ampersand from being misinterpreted when parsing the sandboxed content.

We can achieve this in PHP using `str_replace()`:

```
$srcdoc = '<div id="foo">"Contains quoted text."</div>';
$escaped = str_replace([ '"', '&' ], [ '&quot;', '&amp;amp;' ], $srcdoc);
```

The ampersand replacement shown above is *not a typo*. This code produces:

```
<div id=&quot;foo&quot;>&quot;Contains quoted text.&quot;</div>
```

Then, we can use the escaped value for the `srcdoc` attribute value:

```html
<div id="email_content">
    <iframe sandbox srcdoc="<div id=&quot;foo&quot;>&quot;Contains quoted text.&quot;</div>"></iframe>
</div>
```

Note that the HTML5 srcdoc feature is [not available](https://caniuse.com/#search=srcdoc) in Internet Explorer. Edge supports srcdoc as of version 79 (January 2020). Support in email clients will be even lower.

Comment: Today, srcdoc is Supported in Microsoft Edge (Chromium)  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/status/iframesrcdocattribute/

Comment: Using this replacement code didn't quite work for me as it added two double quotes for some reason, although it can be seen from srcdoc that only one should be included.
This was especially annoying inside of `src` and `href` attributes as it would mess the path.
---
What worked for me was to use single quotes for html element attributes inside of srcdoc, eg. `<script src='path.js'>`.